# Centering a fluid absolutely positioned section

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, centering

So I know this is another centering question but I've been roaming around Google and SO for a couple days now without a solution so I'll ask now.

What I'm trying to do is horizontally center a fluid section element with a max width that has absolutely positioned elements inside it.  The problem is, as you can see in my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7272T/5/), the margins take up 50% of the available space with the other 50% used by the section.  What I would like to do is keep the section perfectly centered but make the margins get smaller as the browser window closes in while keeping the section from re-sizing until the edges of the window gets to it.

I'd like to keep from using any table, table-cell solution because I read on CSS-Tricks that absolutely positioning elements inside table cells can be a real pain.

**Edit** Basically, the goal is to have the content take up as much space as possible without resizing until the view port width forces the content to be responsive.

Thank you for any bump in the right direction.

**HTML:**

```
<section id="wrapper">
    <section id="content">
        <p>Absolutely positioned imgs, btns, etc. go in here</p>
    </section>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
position:absolute;
width:50%;
height:300px;
margin-left:25%;
margin-right:25%;
outline:1px solid red;
}
#content {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;    
max-width:500px;
background:rgb(225, 112, 75);
}
```

Comment: Could you not try margin:0 auto; for the wrapper? That would make the left and right margins dynamically resize... (unless I've misunderstood what you're after).

Comment: @AlexLynham That trick doesn't work on absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: Ahh, I think I misunderstood which absolutely positioned element it was here. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
#content {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

to center your elements that will have a `display:inline-block;` property too.

**EDIT:** Now that I've better read your question, you can also use

```
#content {
        margin:0 25%;
    }
```

to center your second section.

[here's your fiddle updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/7272T/8/)  As you can see by this fiddle everything is centered AND responsive now.

**EDIT-2:** Maybe you want to add some media query to reach your goal. Just add something like this at the end of your CSS file:

```
@media screen and (max-width:720px){
    #content{width:100%; margin:0px;} 
}
```

this says that when screen reaches the width of 720 and under, #content (and every ID/CLASS you put in there) will behave as declared.

NOTE that `@media` queries are not crossbrowser, you may want to add a script to make them work on every browser, I find [**respond.js**](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) a nice tool to do this job.

Also note that the `@media` queries must be placed at least under the default properties that you are about to change on screen resizing, that is why is suggested to add them at the bottom of your css file.

[**HERE is another fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7272T/10/) with media applied (just try to resize the box to see the effect)

Comment: The second section called #content still resizes before the edge of the browser window gets to it.  My main problem is the content box shrinking on resize and only taking up its allotted percentage.  I want to keep that the same until the window is too small and its forced to be responsive.

Comment: i think you should add some @media queries for that. something like `@media screen and (max-width:720px){
    #content{width:100%; margin:0px;} 
}` will do the job. im updating my answer with a fiddle

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but the #content element needs to remain the same width unless the browser window forces it to resize.  Your new example makes the element jumpy and it still resizes when moving the window around.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is what you were looking for: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7272T/7/)

I changed your wrapper to this:

```
#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -200px;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    outline:1px solid red;
}
```

So that your div now sits in the middle of the screen

Comment: This would work if the #content element didn't resize until the edge of the browser window got to it.  But that's my main problem, the #content element is resizing when I want to keep it the same until it's forced to be responsive by the screen width.

Comment: Then you need to use jquery or javascript to change the of the #wrapper as the page gets resized and still display it in px so that the position works and also change the margin-left so that it sits in the center correctly

Comment: Yeah, I'm leaning toward the JS way but I really want to see if this can be done using just CSS.

Comment: You need to use jquery to work out a calculation. I dont know if it is really something that CSS can do and if it can it would only work in new browsers.